# Macro for ensuring that locks are released

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any way I can write a pair of macros for taking and releasing a lock, such that gcc will warn me if I could leave a function without releasing a lock taken previously in that function?

Comment: Use C++ and RAII if you want to guarantee that locks are always released.

Comment: How's that a helpful response?

Comment: @grifaton it's a comment for a reason. He's right, too.

Comment: Ok, I'll just tear up 20 man years of work and rewrite!

Comment: @grifaton stop being such a jerk. It's advice, for God's sake. Take it or don't.

Comment: @grifaton: of course it isn't useful advice, but there's a rule that for certain pairs of languages (X, Y), the comment "don't use X, use Y instead" is wildly cheered by the crowd. (C, C++) apparently is one of those pairs. (C++, Java) probably isn't, it would probably be decided that the person making that comment is the jerk, instead of you. But fundamentally it's just a question of who "the crowd" is at any given moment: in the right forum you'd get a cheer for (C, Fortran) or (C++, Haskell) or even (C++, C). SO questions attract kibitzing, fact of life.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use C; I'm saying that *if* you want guaranteed unlocking, *then* you should use C++ and RAII.  C just doesn't have a language construct for doing this -- it trusts the programmer to write the correct code.  Maybe you can hack something in using OS-specific and/or compiler-specific extensions as given in the answers below, but it will definitely not be standard C.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare a variable without initializing it in the begining macro and initiialize+use it in the ending macro.  If you use the appropriate settings in gcc (`-Wall`?), it should warn you about declared, but not initialized variables.

Note that if you want to use the same macro pair more than once in the same function (e.g. using it with two locks), you will need to specify a different variable name, so you don't end up with an error about re-declaration of variables

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll give it some thought.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your function (scope) may have multiple `return` statements - AFAIK there's no conventional way to do this.

Naturally there's no problem in C++, you may use RAII (an automatic object that unlocks in d'tor).

If you write code for Windows - you may use SEH wrappers to ensure resources release. It'll also work correctly with exceptions (both C++ and SEH).

```
__try
{
    lock(/*...*/);

    // ...

    if (/* ... */)
        return;

} __finally {
    unlock(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer here, mainly because it was meant for exactly this scenario. However, SEH exception methods are bastardizations of the C language, and will wreak havoc if the consumers of your library don't know what's happening. I suppose if you never use `throw` it's fine...

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way to get the compiler to enforce it for you, but can always use a macro instead of the return keyword.  Like this:

```
#define RETURN(x) { if (locked()) unlock();  return x; }
```

That said, personally I hate macros like that, but it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

GCC provides the cleanup attribute which calls a function when a variable goes out of scope. If you have the unlock function:

```
void unlock(lock_t *);
```

You could declare your lock as:

```
lock_t lock __attribute__((cleanup, unlock));
```

Of course the C++ way is more portable and understood.